# Is it possible to make Phoenix a notch less greedy about binary operators?

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup, boost-phoenix

I wanted to have a class category that takes (unevaluated) Phoenix expressions through a binary operator. Basically the idea is that the class processes the expressions and, for example, prints the expression to screen.

The problem is that Phoenix overloads all the binary operators and unless there is an exact match the Phoenix (lazy) operator is preferred. **Is it possible to make the Phoenix just a bit less greedy about hijacking operators?**

Example code:

```
#include<boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include<iostream>
namespace mylib{
    template<class T>
    struct myclass{};

    template<class P, class T>
    auto operator<<(
        myclass<P>& p,
        boost::phoenix::actor<
            boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<
                boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, 
                boost::proto::argsns_::term<T>, 
                0l
            > 
        > const& t
    )->decltype(p){return p << "expression[" << t() << "]";}

}

int main(){
    mylib::myclass<int> A;
    A << boost::phoenix::val(3.); // Doesn't work as expected. Generates a Phoenix `shift``<<` expression. Not the desired outcome.
    mylib::operator<<(A, boost::phoenix::val(3.)); // works as expected
}
```

One solution is to don't overload a binary operator, but the question is more about how to make Phoenix less greedy.

---

**EDIT: An idiomatic workaround, the `hold` function:**

After several unsuccessful tries I changed my opinion and this seems to be a bad idea since one has to fight hard against the Phoenix/Proto system, in which every C++ expression is interpreting as building a Phoenix expression. So, I decided to define a function to leave the Phoenix world temporarily with a hold function.

```
namespace boostx{ // warning: the attempt to deal with rvalues in this code could be wrong, feedback is welcomed
namespace phoenixx{
    template<class T> struct held{
        T release_;
        decltype(auto) release(){return release_;}
        decltype(auto) release() const{return release_;}
        friend decltype(auto) release(held& ht){return ht.release();}
        friend decltype(auto) release(held const& ht){return ht.release();} 
    };

    template<class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<boost::phoenix::is_actor<std::decay_t<T>>::value> >
    held<T> hold(T&& t){
        return {std::forward<T>(t)};
    }
}}
```

(Maybe a function like this already exists (or should exist) in Phoenix, it is complementary to the `actor` class.)

Then the library has a special overload to handle this `held` object that is is `release`d in the right context.

```
namespace mylib{
   ... same as before, plus this new overload ...
    template<class P, class Actor>
    auto operator<<(
        myclass<P>& p,
        boostx::phoenixx::held<Actor> const& ha
    )->decltype(p){
        return mylib::operator<<(p, ha.release());
    }
}
```

Finally, this works:

```
int main(){
    mylib::myclass<int> A;
    A << hold(boost::phoenix::val(3.));
    mylib::operator<<(A, boost::phoenix::val(3.)); // works as expected
}
```

Other functional languages, that I know of, eventually need this kind of functions to suspend eager expression simplification or construction. For example: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html

*Feedback is welcomed.*

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The body `return p << "expression[" << t() << "]";` doesn't makes sense as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I think what you're trying to achieve will be better accomplished using a Proto Transform.

Specifically what you're up against is ADL. And there's no way to make Proto "less greedy" about this, since it's a language mechanism<sup>[1]</sup>.

However, ADL should also pull in `mylib::operator<<`. What gives?

### Fix

Your overload takes the actor by `const&`. Note, however, that if it can be taken by non-const reference, that overload will be preferred. You can take it by value and profit:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e582a97bf9e0bf0)</kbd>**

```
#include<boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include<iostream>

namespace mylib{

    template<class T>
    struct myclass{};

    template<class P, class T>
    auto operator<<(
        myclass<P>& p,
        boost::phoenix::actor<
            boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<
                boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, 
                boost::proto::argsns_::term<T>, 
                0l
            > 
        > t
    )->decltype(p){
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " arg: " << t() << "\n";
        return p; //  << "expression[" << t() << "]";
    }
}

int main(){
    mylib::myclass<int> A;
    A << boost::phoenix::val(3.);
}
```

The version with universal reference is likely a lot cleaner:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c130f87abbdd21d6)</kbd>**

```
template<class P, class Actor>
auto operator<<(myclass<P>& p, Actor&& t) -> decltype(p) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " arg: " << t() << "\n";
    return p;
}
```

You could use tag dispatch or SFINAE to further select on the particular type of Actor

Comment: Taking by value still doesn't help in my `clang++ 3.5.0`. I am also a bit hesitant to make a copy.

Comment: The universal reference version is not resolved, also with an addition of `enable_if`. Tag dispatching will be very painful given that I have many overloads of `mylib::operator<<(myclass<P>& p, ...)` already.

Comment: Wow that's a lot of complaints. The linked live snippets were g++ 4.9, my own machine used _Ubuntu clang version 3.5.0-4ubuntu2~trusty2_. See [clang 3.6.0 **live**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6ada0065de180c4), [g++-4.8 **live**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3acc419048fea82), [g++-4.7 **live**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2862d08f9c9c386), [g++-4.6 **live**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef1b230393a978af) etc.

Comment: Taking by value is not a problem for literal proto expressions; Universal references work (also [on clang++ 3.5.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0751350eb229e3b)). I guess it's fine if you want to _open another question_ with your real problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, messages sound (and are) awful when one writes from a mobile phone. 1) The reason "taking by value" did work for me was that, I realized, there is another level of indirection because `A` is not of type `mylib::myclass<int>` but actually a type _derived_ from `myclass<>`, which makes the case even harder (it had nothing to do with the compiler). 2) I understand that making a copy of a value expression also copies the value object in phoenix, that is why I am hesitant about taking by value.

Comment: ...3) I tried hard with SFINAE (and `is_base_of`) but the line `operator OP(Left &&left, Right &&right)` in `boost/proto/operator.hpp` is very hard to overcome. I'll accept your answer as it is technically correct. I think I will have to use the `mylib::operator<<(,)` syntax. -- Thank you.

Comment: Finally, the "real problem" is just as it sounds. A class that is basically a glorified version of `boost::proto::display_expr`

Comment: I decided to approach the workaround differently, I think one eventually needs to leave the Phoenix world to avoid this problem. See my edit.

Comment: Well. I think the first line of my answer holds the key to a solid solution. Sadly I don't het much experience doing Proto transforms. And the requirements/goals are exceptionally unclear. "Glorified display_expr" doesn't (at all) tell me what it should do.

Comment: Me neither, my experience with Proto (which I don't understand) is through Phoenix (which I do understand at the surface at least). `boost::proto::display_expr` is a function that takes a Proto/Phoenix expression and gives a text representation of it.

Comment: Duh. I know what `display_expr` does. What you _do not tell_ is in what way you want to have it glorified. What do you want to change/add? Otherwise, your problem is solved! Use `display_expr`

Comment: Thanks for interest, what I want to do, first produce a text representation of the expression (that can be compiled) and at a later stage create a runtime tree representation of the expression. Obviously the motivating code was a simplification of all this.